# Getting the text when a tag is in between with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div> <img class="photo" /> text1 </div>
<div> <img class="photo" /> text2 </div>
```

Trying to get text1, text2. I try something like this but it fails,

```
for i in test.find_all(class_="photo"):
     print i.parent[1]
```

Error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the next element in these cases:

```
for elem in test.find_all(class_="photo"):
    print elem.next_sibling
```

Going to the parent would work but then look for the `.stripped_strings` attribute instead:

```
for elem in test.find_all(class_="photo"):
    print ' '.join(elem.parent.stripped_strings)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div> <img class="photo" /> text1 </div>
... <div> <img class="photo" /> text2 </div>
... ''')
>>> for elem in soup.find_all(class_="photo"):
...     print elem.next_sibling
... 
 text1 
 text2 
>>> for elem in soup.find_all(class_="photo"):
...     print ' '.join(elem.parent.stripped_strings)
... 
text1
text2
```

Comment: Second one worked, nice. I had thought first one too initially, but it did not work , I tried again after you said no succes.

Comment: @EmmetB: Then your actual HTML structure is probably different from your sample. Using your exact sample `<div>` tags the `.next_sibling` code works for me, see the sample posted. :-)

Comment: right but for my sample it gives `TypeError: can't pickle HTMLParser objects`. And I copy-pasted your code above (including the soup =..) and still same error.

Comment: @EmmetB: What version of BeautifulSoup? Since `stripped_strings` works, *some* variation of version 4, I presume?

Comment: 4.1.3. Should I use an older version?

Comment: @EmmetB: No, just trying to narrow down why there is a difference. I use 4.1.3 as well. This is then probably the result of a different builder (parser); if you have `lxml` or `html5lib` installed then we can also see different structures.